# Loop on every row in collection except the new row.

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working on a WinApp project using c#. I am using a datagridview and when i am trying to write inside a cell then a new row is created automatically. so if i use 2 rows then a 3rd is created automatically and it is counted in the collection.

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grdCrew.Rows)
        {

        }
```

Thus this statement is executed 3 times insted of two. How can i avoid this and execute the statement 2. ?

Comment: Set the [AllowUserToAddRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows.aspx) property to `fasle` and try again.

Comment: I think he still wants users to be able to add rows, just he doesn't want the blank row to count.

Comment: I think this is the problem, because every time he adds data to a new row a row is created for the user. Anyway, in my opinion, the idea to let user to add rows is error prone.

Comment: @Schaliasos what if you're making a User Entry form?

Comment: @Hans I believe is better to use another form for that where you can validate the data of the user, not directly through the `Datagridview`.

Comment: @Schaliasos so then you'd still need a form that allows user input... and to get that information you'd need to iterate through the rows... I don't see the point you are trying to make

Comment: @Hans the property I am referring is allowing user to add rows to the datagridview by the datagridview itself. When this propert is set to `true` there is always an empty row at the end of the gridview so the user can add more rows(which I think is causing the problem). If he set this property to `false` the last empty row is not displayed. Of course he can still add more rows using another form to tha dataset and then update the gridview to display the new rows.

Answer (score 5):

`DataGridViewRow`s have a `IsNewRow` property that is true if it's the empty row that's inserted by `DataGridView`.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grdCrew.Rows)
{
    if (!row.IsNewRow)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to make a copy of the collection:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grdCrew.Rows.ToArray())
{

}
```